# Using jq to merge two arrays into one array of objects

Tags: json, jq, array-merge

I am very beginner into jq and I want to reshape my JSON file.

I have ve got JSON structured like this:

```
{
   "a": [1, 2, 3, 4 ...],
   "b": [
      {
         "x": 1000,
         "value": 1
      },
      {
         "x": 1000,
         "value": 2
      },
      {
         "x": 1000,
         "value": 3
      }
      ...
   ]
}
```

I am wondering how I can achieve result like this with jq:

```
[
   {
      "value": 1,
      "from": "a",
   },
   {
      "value": 2,
      "from": "a"
   },
   ...
   {
      "value": 1,
      "from": "b"
   },
   {
      "value": 2,
      "from": "b"
   }
   ...
]
```

Comment: Are there always only two fields in the root object?

Comment: Giving an example is nice, but it would be much better if you also described the requirements and showed us what you've tried, which would most likely also give some insight into the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two lists, one from `.a` and one from `.b`, and merge them with `+`.
In the first list, create objects with `value:` set to the original content and add `from: "a"`; in the second list, remove `.x` from elements of `.b` and add the from again.

```
jq '[.a[] | {value:(.), from: "a"}] + [.b[] | del(.x) + {from: "b"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very slightly generic, but hardly robust, solution:

```
map_values( if type == "array" 
            then map(if type == "object" then .value else . end) 
            else . end)
| [ keys_unsorted[] as $k
    | .[$k][] as $v
    | { value: $v, from: $k } ]
```